# mongodb inner query in aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is the simple form of my collection.

```
{ 
  "_id" : "abcdfg", 
  "job_id" : "job_111", 
  "user_id" : "user_001",
  "job_createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-02T15:02:24.122+0000"),
  "score" : 240.91185185185185
}
```

Let's say a user has posted 3 jobs. `job_111, job_112, job_113`. Now `user1,user2,user3,user4` have been matched( means there is a document in the collection) to `job_112 and 113`. And `user5` is matched to all 3 jobs. `user6` is matched exclusively on `job_111`

Now in my aggregation query, I want to show the list of users and number of jobs they have been matched. But there is a condition; users who were matched to `job_112 and job_113`  have higher priority (because they were created recently) and will be shown first. now I have made my query like this

```
[
  { $match: { job_id: { $in: ['job_112', 'job_113'] } } },      
  {
    $group:
      { _id: '$user_id', matched: { $sum: 1 }, score: { $max: '$score' } }
  },
  { $sort: { score: -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit }
]
```

this will return me something like this

```
[
 {
   user_id: 'user1',
   matched: 2
 },
 {
   user_id: 'user2',
   matched: 2
 },
 {
   user_id: 'user4',
   matched: 2
 },
 {
   user_id: 'user5',
   matched: 2
 }
]
```

Now when this list ends(I figure it out using pagination and aggregation count), I want to show users who were matched to `job_111` only. now my query becomes like this

```
[
  { $match: { job_id: { $in: ['job_111'] } } },      
  {
    $group:
      { _id: '$user_id', matched: { $sum: 1 }, score: { $max: '$score' } }
  },
  { $sort: { score: -1 } },
  { $skip: 0 },// << skip value resets to 0 since $in value changes
  { $limit: limit }
]
```

This returns the result something like this

```
[
 {
   user_id: 'user5',
   matched: 1
 },
 {
   user_id: 'user6',
   matched: 1
 },
]
```

Now this result has 2 issues, I don't want to show `user5` again in the list and his matched no is wrong. It is technically 3 but returning 1 because my query made it calculate like 1.

How do I update the aggregation query so that it solves the problem. I know there is way of excluding users putting `$nin` in user field in the find, but I'll not have the list of users beforehand and the list maybe in real scenario few hundreds. Is there any way to find out the list in runtime who were matched in `job_112 and/or job_113` before?

Any suggestion on how to improve this or any other new approach is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one query. You can start with `$match` but including all jobs. Then you can use `$group` with `$push` to collect all jobs for each user. In the last stage there are two possibilities: a `matched` field can be either `1` which represents `job_111` or the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html)-ed array of collected jobs. There won't be less than `1` since there has to be a match from one of those two cases so you can use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) to get `1` or `2`

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { job_id: { $in: ["job_111", "job_112", "job_113"] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            jobs: { $push: "$job_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            matched: {
                $max: [ 1,
                    {  
                        $size: { 
                            $filter: { 
                                input: "$jobs", 
                                as: "job", 
                                cond: { $in: [ "$$job", ["job_112", "job_113"] ] } 
                            }   
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I guess this will solve the incorrect match number and duplicate `user5` issues. but will lead to another problem. which is `user6` may come on top of the list based on its score value. users who exclusively matched to older jobs(`job_111` here) need to be shown after all the users are shown from latest jobs.

Comment: solved it adding few tweaks. i'm marking this as correct since you got me the idea of how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I'm posting the solution that finally worked for me

```
[
  { $match: find },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$user_id',
      jobs: { $push: '$job_id' },
      matched: { $sum: 1 },
      score: { $max: '$score' }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id',
      matched: '$matched',
      score: '$score',
      jobs: '$jobs',
      rangeType: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $setIntersection: ['$jobs',['job_112', 'job_113'] ]
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          then: 10,
          else: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { rangeType: -1, score: -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit }
]
```